# Python regexp: get all group's sequence

Tags: python, regex

I have a regex like this `'^(a|ab|1|2)+$'` and want to get all sequence for this...

for example for re.search(reg, 'ab1') I want to get ('ab','1')

Equivalent result I can get with `'^(a|ab|1|2)(a|ab|1|2)$'` pattern, 
but I don't know how many blocks been matched with (pattern)+

Is this possible, and if yes - how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original expression does match the way you want to, it just matches the entire string and doesn't capture individual groups for each separate match. Using a repetition operator ('+', '*', '{m,n}'), the group gets overwritten each time, and only the final match is saved. This is alluded to in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group):

> If a group matches multiple times, only the last match is accessible.

Comment: Please, don't make assumptions, you broke expression too. My regexp is `^(term1|term2|...|termN)+$`. all terms same urgency, we can't regroup them... 
in other words: I want get `['ab','1']` from `'ab1'`, but also `['1', 'ab']` from `'1ab'`, and even `['1', 'ab', 'a', '1','2']` from `'1aba12'`

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I misunderstood. Can you really not remove '^' and '$'? If not, why not?

Comment: I can't, Because I need full-string match, without any artifacts...
All that I need, I can get with `'^(pattern)(pattern)*(pattern)*(pattern)*(pattern)*(pattern)*(pattern)*(pattern)*(pattern)*$'`
In this case(if I write more patterns than need for matching) I get, that I need plus some empty rows

I need to know: Is there some way to get more than one matched value for a one pair parenthes, when it match more than time `(pattern)+`

Comment: Well, your original expression does match the way you want to, it just doesn't capture individual groups for each separate match. Using a repetition operator ('+', '*', '{m,n}'), the group gets overwritten each time, and only the final match is saved. You might need to either rethink what you're trying to do and why, or else look for alternative solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I think you should add info about group overwriting to your answer

Comment: How about doing this in multiple stages? E.g., first verify that the entire string fits your pattern (`if re.search("^(?:(?:a|ab|1|2))+$", "aa1ab2"):`), and if it does, only then retrieve all of the matches (`re.findall("(ab|a|1|2)", "aa1ab2")`) and do whatever you need with them.

Comment: I miss right matches order and repeats in this case. Thanks, question is closed... I implement this without regexp...

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
import re
r = re.compile('(ab|a|1|2)')
for i in r.findall('ab1'):
    print i
```

The `ab` option has been moved to be first, so it will match `ab` in favor of just `a`.
findall method matches your regular expression more times and returns a list of matched groups. In this simple example you'll get back just a list of strings. Each string for one match. If you had more groups you'll get back a list of tuples each containing strings for each group.

This should work for your second example:

```
pattern = '(7325189|7325|9087|087|18)'
str = '7325189087'
res = re.compile(pattern).findall(str)
print(pattern, str, res, [i for i in res])
```

I'm removing the `^$` signs from the pattern because if findall has to find more than one substring, then it should search anywhere in str. Then I've removed `+` so it matches single occurences of those options in pattern.

Comment: Is it difference from 

`print(i for i in [re.findall(pattern, s)])`

? 
        Both prints only first group ('ab') for me :(

Comment: wait do you see `ab` and then `1` or only `ab`? if you see both then there should be no problem. Could you please show more examples of input and desired output?

Comment: I see only 'ab', no '1'

Comment: `> print(pattern, str, res, [i for i in res])`
`^(7325189|7325|9087|087|18)+$ 7325189087 ['087'] ['087']`

And I want to get ['7325189','087'] here. Or [['7325189','087'],['7325','18','9087']]

Comment: Hmm i've removed the `^` and `$` for the pattern to be able to match more occurences. I'm not sure now what do you want to achieve.

Comment: To understand what I want: only one occurence matched(may be multipath, but one full match)  `^(a|b)+$` Here a or b may to match many times, and my answer how I can get sequence for this?
Ex: foo('^(a|b)+$', 'aaab') -> ['a','a','a','b']

Comment: Without ^$ and +... It's wrong solution :( It simple find matches
I need right sequence which regexp parser used for a full string match
'(1|2)' for '213' give me [2, 1], but I want doesn't match here: '^(1|2)+$'

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need regexpes for this problem,
you need some recursial graph search function